# flutter scrollview not scrolling

Tags: dart, flutter

I have this

```
  Widget _Project() {
return new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: Card(
              color: _Cardcolor,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Projects',
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 40.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0, right: 50.0, top: 10.0),
            height: 130.0,
            width: 15.0,
          ),
          Divider(
            height: 40,
          ),
          Container(
            child:  FutureBuilder<List<Project>>(
              future: fetchProjects(http.Client()),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
                return snapshot.hasData
                    ? ProjectList(projects: snapshot.data)
                    : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
    ) ;
  }
```

and this is the builder

```
class ProjectList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Project> projects;
  ProjectList({Key key, this.projects}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: projects.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                color: Colors.white10,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Card(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text(projects[index].ProjectId),
                        subtitle: Text(projects[index].ProjectId),
                      ),
                      ButtonTheme.bar(
                        // make buttons use the appropriate styles for cards
                        child: ButtonBar(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            FlatButton(
                              child: const Text('Open'),
                              onPressed: () {/* ... */},
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

So, i'm creating the `list` with card. Here is the screenshot

[image]

the data is from json and it is showing properly. Well, it is not showing properly because i have 5 and it is only showing 3, well it is because the scrolling problem. When i make the card smaller all of my data is showing up.

I already try to add this line

```
 physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()
```

But still no help, I'm stuck now

How can i fix it ? did i miss something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Your class - `ProjectList()` - `ListView.builder` - add - `physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),`

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),  // add this
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: projects.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[ ...
```

update:
To make the `card list` scroll only not the whole page - replace top `Listview` with the `column`.

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Column(   // replace from listview
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 15.0,),
          Container(
            child: Card(
              //  color: _Cardcolor,
              child: Text(
                'Projects',
                style: new TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 44.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0, right: 50.0, top: 15.0),
            height: 130.0,
           // width: 15.0,
          ),
          Divider(
            height: 40,
          ),
          Expanded( // add Expanded
            child: Container(
              child: ProjectList(
                projects: ['anmol', 'anmol', 'dummy', 'demo'],
              ),
//            child: FutureBuilder<List<Project>>(
//              future: fetchProjects(http.Client()),
//              builder: (context, snapshot) {
//                if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
//                return snapshot.hasData
//                    ? ProjectList(projects: snapshot.data)
//                    : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
//              },
//            ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: i only want the scroll in `card list` area, is it possible ? sorry for my english

Comment: thanks, it is fixed my problem. Now i just need to edit the `text`. Btw, do i need to use scaffold ? because i already use it in my `ModalProgressHUD` ?